# Changing desktop folder

Tags: windows-xp, desktop, special-locations

I know that this question is replied thousand times but,
I change Desktop folder of my Windows XP by Regedit, from `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders`
I change "Desktop" value to "C:\MynewDesktop"

Then I close regedit, go back to my desktop an I press `F5`. I take this error:

> c:\Myfancydesktop is unknown location. It may be in hard disk or in
>   network.

The error gives the folder name of my old desktop. But I deleted that folder.

I reopen regedit and check for `Desktop` key. I see that value is empty.
So how can I change my desktop folder in XP?

Answer (score 1):

> I change Desktop folder of my Windows XP by Regedit, from HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders I change "Desktop" value to "C:\MynewDesktop"

That is the wrong key. You should not modify the values in `Shell Folders`, you should modify them in `User Shell Folders`. When you boot, Windows reads the values in `User Shell Folders`, expands any environment variables, then copies them to `Shell Folders`.

> Then I close regedit, go back to my desktop an I press F5. I take this error:
>
> ```
> c:\Myfancydesktop is unknown location. It may be in hard disk or in network.
> ```
>
> The error gives the folder name of my old desktop. But I deleted that folder.

Because you need to reboot (or log out and back in) for the new value to take effect (assuming you modify the correct value of course).

> I reopen regedit and check for Desktop key. I see that value is empty.

Because Explorer over-wrote it.

> So how can I change my desktop folder in XP?

Edit the `Desktop` value under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders`. You can use environment variables there, just make sure to leave it as a `REG_EXPAND_SZ`.

Answer (score 0):

You should change path to new folder here as well:

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders`

Read for more: [How to redirect special folders in Windows XP?](http://windowsxp.mvps.org/redirectfolders.htm)

And I strongly recommend you to install that TweakXP tool for doing such things using pretty UI, not manually)

Answer (score -1):

I have not experienced any trouble with this so far but what I did with my installation was to search the registry for the 'keyword', say, "Desktop", and then changed every occurrence of that key to the folder I want. You'll figure it out. Because some keys have redundant entries and changing one will not update the other if the other is not linked to the other.